# Problema al actualizar +1 en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este problema:
Estoy haciendo un pequeño código que necesito para saber si una IP que ya llegó a mi sitio está duplicada en la base de datos y si es así que actualice +1 en el campo visitas.
El problema esta en que no agrega +1 sino +2  y no entiendo por qué hace esto, gracias por sus comentarios desde ya.

Este es mi código PHP:

```html
<?php 
$aguila = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "database");
if (!$aguila){
  echo  "No se puede conectar a la base de datos";
}
$ip = $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ];
$consulta = mysqli_query( $aguila, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM stats WHERE ip='$ip'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta);
if($row->total > 0){
$actualiza = "UPDATE stats SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE ip='$ip'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($aguila, $actualiza);
}else{
    echo "Si no esta en la base de datos, lo guardo...";
}
?>
```

Y esta es mi Base de datos:
[image: Base de datos]

Comment: Estás seguro que este código sólo se ejecuta una vez por cada visita del usuario?

Comment: Alfabravo, si amigo, de hecho solo este codigo es el que hay en un archivo index.php

Comment: Primero `count(*)` no aplica aqui debe ser visitas as total segundo ese no es todo el codigo asi que si tiene un loop o algo mas no sabemos no podremos ayudarte solo especulando!

Comment: Bryro, acabo de escribir arriba que si es todo el codigo, no hay nada mas. el código que ves ahí es lo que hay

Comment: Al parecer te debe de hacer dos consultas por alguna razón. Utiliza el network del navegador (pulsando F12) para ver las peticiones.

Comment: A simple vista, el código no debería sumar +2 sino +1, se debe estar llamando dos veces por algún motivo: ¿Tienes el código en otra parte del proyecto? ¿Desde dónde se llama/incluye? ¿Tienes alguna redirección creada en el servidor?

Comment: El visitas + 1 deberías cogerlo de la respuesta de la consulta SQL del count, que ni siquiera lleva el $ delante, a saber de donde lo obtienes, y el $ip debería llevar puntos delante y detrás para concatenar, WHERE ip = ". $ip;

Comment: Puedes crear una 2ª tabla de prueba (con otro nombre), para descartar que el script no se ejecuta en alguna parte olvidada. De paso puedes probar otro tipo de consulta que se llama [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), la cual te permite con una sola sentencia insertar la fila si no existe, o actualizarla si existe. La única condición es que `ip` sea `UNIQUE` o sea `PRIMARY KEY` lo cual debería ser así. La sentencia:  **`INSERT INTO stats (ip,fecha,visitas) VALUES ('$ip',now(),1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visitas=visitas+1;`**